# Buffered I/O address allocation

Tags: c++, io, stream, buffer, fopen

I am interested in low-level implementations of useful functions which i tend to analyze in terms of exploit. So here is a question which i have been surfing the web for the last two days and i haven't found a clear answer.
You may already know what when we are using functions such as [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/), we are actually using buffers for I/O operations.

I want to know where these buffers are located in the memory.

Comment: This is implementation dependent. Dive into the source and assembly code with a debugger to get an answer for one specific implementation/platform.

Comment: Not specified, but you can provide your own buffer with `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()`.